# json KeyError with json.loads

Tags: python, json

JSON seems to be hiccuping on the following statements:

```
{"delete":{"status":{"id":12600579001,"user_id":55389449}}}
```

code snippet:

```
temp = json.loads(line)
text = temp['text']
```

I get the following error output when the above code snippet encounters lines similar to the above JSON 'dictionary':

```
text = temp['text']
KeyError: 'text'
```

Is it because there is no "text" key in the line or because "delete" is not in the dictionary?

Comment: The `"delete"` key *is* in the dictionary. The `"text"` key is not. "The line" is not relevant; once you have parsed the JSON with `json.loads`, the result is **just** a nested dictionary, which you deal with *the same way* that you would deal with *the same data structure* if you had gotten it *in any other way*.

Answer (score 14):

It looks like this happens because 'text' is not in there. Maybe you could use something like

```
'text' in temp
```

to check that 'text' exists before trying to use it.

**Edit:**

I've taken the example given in the comment and added a if/elif/else block to it.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
import json
f = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in f:
    j = json.loads(line)
    try:
        if 'text' in j:
            print 'TEXT: ', j['text']
        elif 'delete' in j:
            print 'DELETE: ', j['delete']
        else:
            print 'Everything: ', j
    except: 
        print "EXCEPTION: ", j
```

Sample Chunk #1:

> {u'favorited': False, u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': ---- snip ---- }

Sample Chunk #2:

> {u'delete': {u'status': {u'user_id': 55389449, u'id': 12600579001L}}}

Comment: I thought that was the problem and jinned up the code below:

#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import json

f = open(sys.argv[1])


for line in f:
 
 j = json.loads(line)
 
 try:
  'text' in j  
  print "TEXT:  ", j
 except:
  print "EXCEPTION:   ", j
  continue

and get the following results (only two sample chunks)... 

TEXT:   {u'favorited': False, u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text':  ---- snip ---- }

TEXT:   {u'delete': {u'status': {u'user_id': 55389449, u'id': 12600579001L}}}

Comment: I added a modified version of your code to my answer. Does this work for your file?

Comment: This got me past the first hurdle. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

use [dict.get(key[, default])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) if there is a *valid* case when the key is missing:
`temp.get('text')` instead of `temp['text']`
won’t throw an exception but return the null value `None` if the key is not found.

EAFP (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission) is more Pythonic than LBYL (Look Before You Leap).

Comment: This solved my issue.  Note that in certain situations returning Null ("None" in python) will be a problem for further processing, therefore you can change what the value should be if the key is missing by using temp.get('text', 'X') where X is a string

Comment: @lobi feel free to edit the answer to add that info and get two reputation points ;)

Answer (score 8):

> Is it because there is no "text" key in the line or because "delete" is not in the dictionary?

It's because there is no "text" key.  If you `print temp` or check whether the key `'text'` is in the resulting Python dictionary, you'll notice that there is no key named `'text'`.  In fact, `temp` only has one key: `'delete'`.  The dictionary that is referenced by `'delete'` contains a single key `'status'` that contains another dictionary with two keys: `'user_id'` and `'id'`.

In other words, your structure is this:

```
{
    "delete" : {
        "status" : {
            "id" : 12600579001,
            "user_id" : 55389449
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no "text" key anywhere.

Furthermore, you can check it yourself:

```
>>> 'text' in temp
False
>>> 'delete' in temp
True
```

Answer (score 2):

From the snippet you posted, it looks like `temp` should only have one item, with the key `"delete"`. You do not have a key `'text'`, so I am not sure what `temp['text']` should look up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to see the problem in detail:

```
import json
line = '{"delete":{"status":{"id":12600579001,"user_id":55389449}}}'
print 'line:', line
temp = json.loads(line)
print 'temp:', json.dumps(temp, indent=4)
print 'keys in temp:', temp.keys()
```

Which generates this output:

```
line: {"delete":{"status":{"id":12600579001,"user_id":55389449}}}
temp: {
    "delete": {
        "status": {
            "user_id": 55389449, 
            "id": 12600579001
        }
    }
}
keys in temp: [u'delete']
```

The only key in the `temp` dict is 'delete'.  Thus `temp['text']` generates a KeyError.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put this between the first and second lines:

```
print temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for the suggestions. The heart of the problem was that the Twitter json format has a dictionary within a dictionary.  The solution involves a double index to get at the variables that I need to check.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
    temp = json.load(line)
    for lines in temp
       text = lines['text']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an updated version of the verified answer.

If the frequency of that error happening (meaning that the variable `text` does not exist in the json file) is below 50% then the way to go is with the desired answer.

But if the exception is really exceptional you should use

```
try:
   #your code here
except KeyError:
   continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import json
from pprint import pprint


json_file=sys.argv[1]
json_data=open(json_file)
j = json.load(json_data)

def main():
  for attribute_key in j['root_attribute']:
   try: print attribute_key['name'], attribute_key['status'], attribute_key['text']
   except KeyError: pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```