# How to handle keyError in python and continue execution?

Tags: python

My python rest API receives a JSON and extracts the values from keys.

Problem: The program throws a keyError and exits if any one key is not present or if the keys' value is null. The function is not inside a loop.

I want the program to continue execution even if the key is not present.

Comment: So, catch the exception with `except`. Or use a form like `.get` that doesn't throw.

Comment: Also, did you try searching Google first? There are so many duplicate QA on Stack Overflow that I don't even know which one to choose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json KeyError with json.loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687225/json-keyerror-with-json-loads)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in Python is:

```
try:
    extract = json_resp[key]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Alternatively you can use get, with a default:

```
extract = json_resp.get(key, default)
```

Which fall back to the default if the key isn't present in the dictionary.