# DOn't understand KeyError:

Tags: python

I am trying to create an interactive dictionary. The file data.json is where the definition of the words are stored. I expected the code to look up the definition of a word as entered by the user and print it out in the terminal.

```
import json

data = json.load(open("data.json", 'r'))
item = input("Enter word you are looking for: ")
data["%s", item]
print(data)
```

However I keep getting the following error

```
Enter word you are looking for: rain
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\eclipse-workspace\FTS\src\FirstModule.py", line 10, in <module>
    data["%s", item]
KeyError: ('%s', 'rain')
```

I don't understand what is causing the error or how to fix it. Can someone please point out where I am making the mistake and suggest a possible solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `data.json`?

Comment: `data["%s", item]` cannot be a valid key for a JSON object. Did you mean only `data[item]`?

Comment: I believe this SO question might have what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687225/json-keyerror-with-json-loads

Answer (score 1):

Just change `data["%s", item]` to `data[item]`. You have a string stored in the item variable, and you want that to be used as the index into your dictionary. That should resolve the key error.

Answer (score 0):

That KeyError means just that the tuple `('%s', 'rain')` does not exists in your dictionary.

Now you must ask yourself why would you want such object (that tuple) to be a key in your dictionary and why is not present yet.